# willDisplayCell and UITableViewCell label background colors

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My question relates to [stackoverflow 1184014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184014/removing-text-shadow-in-uitableviewcell-when-its-selected).
Basically I have customized the background of my UITableViewCell (clear color) in my

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and it's all good until I overlay an UIActionSheet over the Table.

If the currently selected cell is under the action sheet when I cancel the action sheet the background of the labels in my cell becomes black. This does not happen if the cell is not covered by the action sheet.

To fix this I have called

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

in the action sheet delegate method (on cancel) but that seems like a poor solution.
Is there another way to force the tableView to repaint that cell once the action sheet is cancelled?

Note: once the cell is dequeued it comes back to normal. On the other hand selecting another cell or scrolling does not.

Cheers...

Comment: I'd file a bug report because Apple is constantly doing bad undocumented voodoo with table cells behind your back, this being just a single example. Whenever I need to do *anything* with table cells, I just don't use its labels and image view, otherwise it invariably opens a can of worms.

Comment: Thanks. I am considering that. I just thought I would ask around / google before doing it.