# How to Prevent Shadow at the top of grouped UITableViewCell from appearing & disappearing when selected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to disallow selection of certain UITableViewCells in a grouped table. 
Using selectionStyle = UITableViewSelectionStyleNone works and so does willSelectRowAtIndexPath.

The issue is at the top of each of the groups of cells there is a shadow that disappears when a finger touches down on the top cell and reappears when it lifts off. How do I turn it off?

Thanks =)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am having the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

That shadow is from the `UITableView` "Separator" dropdown in Interface Builder: "Single Line Etched". The best way to handle it is subclass `UITableViewCell` to prevent the cell from changing the highlight:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {}
    [super setHighlighted:NO animated:animated];
}
```

For more details, check out [Removing text shadow in UITableViewCell when it's selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184014/removing-text-shadow-in-uitableviewcell-when-its-selected).