# Why is my detailTextLabel moving?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using the following code in my subclass of `UITableViewCell` to set a drop shadow for unselected cells in my `UITableView`

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
  [self applyLabelDropShadow:!highlighted];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
  [self applyLabelDropShadow:!selected];
}

- (void)applyLabelDropShadow:(BOOL)applyDropShadow
{
  self.textLabel.shadowColor = applyDropShadow ? [UIColor whiteColor] : nil;
  self.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
  self.detailTextLabel.shadowColor = applyDropShadow ? [UIColor whiteColor] : nil;
  self.detailTextLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
}
```

This code from another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184014/removing-text-shadow-in-uitableviewcell-when-its-selected) by [Mike Stead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83030/mike-stead) and it works fine.

When the row moves from selected to deselected however, you can see the `detailTextLabel` shift down very slightly which I don't want to happen.  This doesn't happen to the `textLabel` for the cell.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `[UIColor clearColor]` for the non-shadow instead of `nil`:

```
- (void)applyLabelDropShadow:(BOOL)applyDropShadow
{
  self.textLabel.shadowColor = applyDropShadow ? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor clearColor];
  self.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
  self.detailTextLabel.shadowColor = applyDropShadow ? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor clearColor];
  self.detailTextLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
}
```

Comment: That fixed it, but why doesn't it happen to the `textLabel` with the same code?

Comment: It could be a pixel-boundry issue, where the size of textLabel is different than the size of detailTextLabel.  The one pixel offset affects one visibly and not the other.

Comment: Makes sense, accepted your answer.  Had to wait the obligatory cooling off period....